# Is there a way to use [FIELD variable_name] with an already gathered list?

Tags: docassemble

I am just reading the documents, getting prepared to write some list-gathering questions.

I have looked at the docs about groups, and specifically I'm looking at the documentation about editing already gathered lists (https://docassemble.org/docs/groups.html#editing).

I also notice, however, that `docassemble` supports "embedding fields within a paragraph." (https://docassemble.org/docs/groups.html#editing).

I'm just thinking how useful it might be to combine these two concepts -- rather than have the user hit the "edit" button and go through redefining the whole row, perhaps there is a way to pre-populate the fields (eg. with a default) and then save any updated information upon the press of `continue` / `save`, using `[FIELD variable_name]`?

There's also that `add another` functionality for lists, which might also be interesting to combine with the same screen that lists the editable information using `[FIELD]`.

I suppose a similar set of functionality might be achieved by a question of this sort (https://docassemble.org/docs/groups.html#list%20collect), and a review screen where (presumably) any click on an edit button would take you back to the big list?

Any template / best-practices / comments on the possibility of this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[FIELD ...]` feature cannot be used with variable names that contain a `]`.

Your best bet is to use a `list collect` interface, which allows the user to edit all of the rows on one screen.